# In Symfony, how to get QueryBuilder from default findBy method?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In Symfony 5, using Doctrine, how can I get QueryBuilder object (instead of results) from default entity repository methods like *findBy*, *findOneBy*, *findAll*?

I need QueryBuilder for:

1. Passing it to KnpPaginator (requires specifically QueryBuilder instead of results)
2. Possibly extending it with additional query logic in the future

I could just write a simple query (like `$em->createQuery("SELECT a FROM Article a")`), but I want to have access to filtering and ordering provided by default *findBy* method. I think writing my own QueryBuilder with filtering/sorting by any property would be a lot of work and I'm not sure I could implement it well even if I tried.

*EDIT:* even though it does not answer my question exactly, I have found a solution for my 1st use case (using KnpPaginator without writing custom queries): [Custom data repository pagination](https://github.com/KnpLabs/knp-components/blob/master/docs/pager/intro.md#custom-data-repository-pagination).
This method allows to attach pagination to any query without changing it instead of writing a new one through QueryBuilder.

Comment: I think if you look in the source for the findBy and related methods you will find that duplicating it it pretty trivial.  You will also see that the underlying query builder object is not exposed.

Comment: I have looked in the source and saw that there's no QueryBuilder there. So do those methods don't use QueryBuilder at all and it's impossible to get a query from them? I hoped that maybe QueryBuilder is used somewhere in deeper levels and I just can't figure out how to get it.

Comment: Good question, it would indeed be a nice feature if possible. But I think it is impossible indeed because there is no QueryBuilder involved in those methods. It is not compatible with KnpPaginator... Luckily those methods (findBy, findAll, find) are not the most difficult to write yourself. You could extend EntityRepository MyEntityRepository and write your own methods (findAllQb, findByQb, findQb) and then use those instead